# How to get the line of a crash in Swift from a crash log stack trace

Tags: ios, swift, crash, crash-dumps

I have a crash log from a production build of an app. How do I figure out the exact line of code it crashed on? Needless to say this problem is not reproducible on any devices in the office.

```
Incident Identifier: 8ECB1402-12E9-4869-A5FE-DB5DD2383EDA
CrashReporter Key:   TODO
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,2
Process:         Argus [2287]
Path:            /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/BB7F6F60-2E8E-46A5-988E-38B9F618C254/Argus.app/Argus
Identifier:      com.azumio.iphone.argus
Version:         3.12.370
Code Type:       ARM
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2015-01-24 02:55:02 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 8.1.2 (12B440)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGTRAP
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x1d64d4
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   Argus                               0x001d64d4 Argus.AZPedometerStepsSync.updateStatsToCheckIn (Argus.AZPedometerStepsSync)([Argus.AZPedometerData], checkIn : ObjectiveC.AZCheckIn) -> () + 7580
1   Argus                               0x001de830 Argus.AZPedometerStepsSync.(startLiveImport (Argus.AZPedometerStepsSync) -> (Swift.Int, checkIn : ObjectiveC.AZCheckIn, startWithFastImport : Swift.Bool) -> ()).(closure #1) + 136
2   Argus                               0x001d8840 partial apply forwarder for Argus.AZPedometerStepsSync.(startLiveImport (Argus.AZPedometerStepsSync) -> (Swift.Int, checkIn : ObjectiveC.AZCheckIn, startWithFastImport : Swift.Bool) -> ()).(closure #1) + 100
3   Argus                               0x001d88ac partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@owned [Argus.AZPedometerData], @unowned Swift.Int) -> (@unowned ()) to @callee_owned (@in (data : [Argus.AZPedometerData], importNumber : Swift.Int)) -> (@out ()) + 56
4   Argus                               0x001cb4e4 Argus.StepsImportQueue.addToQueue (Argus.StepsImportQueue)(Argus.AZPedometerData) -> () + 1688
5   Argus                               0x001ddcb8 Argus.StepsImportQueue.(importForMinute (Argus.StepsImportQueue) -> (ObjectiveC.NSDate, endDate : ObjectiveC.NSDate, minute : Swift.Int) -> ()).(closure #1) + 1240
6   Argus                               0x001d89b0 partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@owned Argus.AZPedometerData!, @owned ObjectiveC.NSError!) -> (@unowned ()) to @callee_owned (@in (Argus.AZPedometerData!, ObjectiveC.NSError!)) -> (@out ()) with unmangled suffix "187" + 56
7   Argus                               0x001dd2b0 Argus.AZStepCounter.(queryStepCountStartingFrom8 (Argus.AZStepCounter) -> (ObjectiveC.NSDate!, to : ObjectiveC.NSDate!, toQueue : ObjectiveC.NSOperationQueue!, withHandler : (Argus.AZPedometerData!, ObjectiveC.NSError!) -> ()!) -> ()).(closure #1).(closure #1).(closure #1) + 756
8   Argus                               0x001da144 partial apply forwarder for Argus.AZStepCounter.(queryStepCountStartingFrom8 (Argus.AZStepCounter) -> (ObjectiveC.NSDate!, to : ObjectiveC.NSDate!, toQueue : ObjectiveC.NSOperationQueue!, withHandler : (Argus.AZPedometerData!, ObjectiveC.NSError!) -> ()!) -> ()).(closure #1).(closure #1).(closure #1) + 140
9   Foundation                          0x2a0c02b1 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 9
10  Foundation                          0x2a02b34d -[NSBlockOperation main] + 149
11  Foundation                          0x2a01db07 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 775
12  Foundation                          0x2a0c2c1b __NSOQSchedule_f + 187
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3710c7a7 _dispatch_client_callout + 23
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3710ffa3 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 719
15  CoreFoundation                      0x2938b3b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
16  CoreFoundation                      0x29389ab1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1513
17  CoreFoundation                      0x292d73c1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 477
18  CoreFoundation                      0x292d71d3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
19  GraphicsServices                    0x306950a9 GSEventRunModal + 137
20  UIKit                               0x2c8e6fa1 UIApplicationMain + 1441
21  Argus                               0x0024a3a7 main + 59
22  libdyld.dylib                       0x3712caaf start + 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, Apple suggests to find the thread that is the problem. You have that clearly defined there in:

```
Crashed Thread:  0
```

So then they advise to read the uppermost statement (nearest to 0) that has your app name on it (lest part of the statement). If I'm not mistaken, this should be the problem method:

```
Argus.AZPedometerStepsSync.updateStatsToCheckIn
```

Comment: Hi, Yes this is clear. but the question is which line in `Argus.AZPedometerStepsSync.updateStatsToCheckIn`

Comment: Arg, sorry didn't pay enough attention.. I have no idea and would really like for someone to enlighten us!